# Update svn:ignore Using Subclipse

Tags: svn, subclipse, svnignore

I have an existing application that I checked out from SVN. Say it was something like the following:

```
MyApp
-- MyFolderA
```

There is already a svn:ignore property on the application. It currently ignores:

1. .project
2. .settings
3. .classpath

I added a new folder to the project and committed the folder to SVN. So now I have:

```
MyApp
-- MyFolderA
-- MyFolderB
```

Now when I try to commit my code, there are new files (e.g. MyFolderB/.project) in the list of files to commit.

I need to update the svn:ignore property. I went to Team > Show Properties on the project.  I double clicked on the snv:ignore property and added `MyFolderB\.project` and clicked OK. However, when I go to commit, the file still appears as one of the files being committed.

I've tried updating the project, refreshing it, etc. As well as using forward and back slashes, different paths, etc. But the file is still there in the commit files. It has not been added to the repository or anything. Does anyone know how to actually get the file to be ignored on commits? Do I need to push the  svn:ignore update to the repository somehow or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are setting the `svn:ignore` property not on the right directory.

From [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html):

> And it's worth noting again that, unlike the global-ignores option,
>   the patterns found in the svn:ignore property apply only to the
>   directory on which that property is set, and not to any of its
>   subdirectories.

So try to set `svn:ignore` directly on the `MyFolderB`:

1. Right-click on the `MyFolderB`
2. Choose `Team` -> `Show Properties`
3. Add a `svn:ignore` property or edit it if it already exist
4. Add a new line with value `.project`
5. Save the property value

Comment: +1 Thanks. Putting the ignore rule on the lower directory worked.